# All Portal 2 Achievements and how to get them

Tags: achievements, portal-2

Being the achievement whore that I am, and knowing that others out there are as well, I thought it'd be good to have a centralized place where you can see what you have to do to get them all.

Comment: Technically, High Five is earned for completing the Calibration Course.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo @Billare That's the point. It's an answer disguised as a question. However, I personally think it's a bit too broad for one question, maybe several just for the achievements that are not obvious.

Comment: @Bilare Because it's better suited as a tutorial/guide/blog post; I'd rather have a question per "interesting" achievement.

Comment: @fail badp @BoltClock I still don't think this is that bad, phrased a super answer to a question.  Have you perused through the Android Stack's super Android upgrade threads?  I feel like this is like that.  Obviously those threads are great resources for many people and get alot of views.   We wouldn't completely encourage this sort of thing of course, but as a C/W answer I think it would work.   People would post annotations of what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @Billare Where did I say it's bad?

Answer (score 0):

### Single-Player Achievements

These achievements are unlocked in the single player campaign

#### Story-Progression Achievements

You will get these achievements just by playing all the way through the single player campaign.  To avoid spoilers, these just have the achievement description next to them.

- **Wake Up Call** - Survive the manual override
- **You Monster** - Reunite with GLaDOS
- **Undiscouraged** - Complete the first Thermal Discouragement Beam test
- **Bridge Over Troubling Water** - Complete the first Hard Light Bridge test
- **SaBOTour** - Make a break for it
- **Stalemate Associate** - Press the button!
- **Tater Tote** - Carry science forward
- **Vertically Unchallenged** - Master the Repulsion Gel
- **Stranger Than Friction** - Master the Propulsion Gel
- **White Out** - Complete the first Conversion Gel test
- **Tunnel of Funnel** - Master the Excursion Funnel
- **Dual Pit Experiment** - Do the same test twice
- **The Part Where He Kills You** - This is that part
- **Lunacy** - That just happened

#### Optional Achievements

You actually have to earn these by doing specific tasks in the single player campaign.
**Many of these videos show how to beat certain chambers and should be considered spoilers**

- **Drop Box** - Place a cube on a button without touching the cube - [Easiest to do in ch. 2 chamber 6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJKdzpTp034)
- **Pturretdactyl** - Use an Aerial Faith Plate to launch a turret - [This can be done in the same chamber as Drop Box, ch. 2 chamber 6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJKdzpTp034)
- **Preservation of Mass** - Break the rules in Test Chamber 07 - [Try to rescue your companion cube! in ch. 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9e9Ouo3KbLM)
- **Overclocker** - Complete Test Chamber 10 in 70 seconds - [Ch. 3; See one way to do it here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahA2wc5GGGg)
- **Good Listener** - Take GLaDOS' escape advice - [Listening doesn't always pay off. Ch. 4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbTXHuytW6g)
- **No Hard Feelings** - Save a turret from redemption - [Whether or not you choose to then vaporize it later is optional. Ch. 5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtSBpbmN820)
- **You Made Your Point** - Refuse to solve the first test in Chapter 8 - *You literally just sit there a minute until you get it. This is the test Wheatley says he made up himself, with "TEST" written on the wall; not the first chamber where he's trying to get boxes to walk onto a button.*
- **Pit Boss** - Show that pit who's boss - [Take a leap of faith for Wheatley](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxLZvSBNGUg)
- **Final Transmission** - Find the hidden signal in one of the Rat Man's dens - [Also done in the same room as Drop Box, Ch. 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LEDH1BJTn4)
- **Scanned Alone** - Stand in a defective turret detector - *Fairly self-explanatory once you get to that part of the story; Ch. 5*
- **Schrodinger's Catch** - Catch a blue-painted box before it touches the ground - *Also fairly self-explanatory once you get to that part of the story; Ch. 6*
- **Ship Overboard** - Discover the missing experiment - *see Door Prize; Ch. 6*
- **Door Prize** - Examine all the vitrified test chamber doors - [This shows the location of all the doors, which will lead you to the missing experiment; Ch. 6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jI97sfTOc6s&feature=player_embedded)
- **Portrait of a Lady** - Find a hidden portrait - [Find her here; Ch. 7](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNdaVFgywOo)
- **Smash TV** - Break 11 test chamber monitors - [You know what he's got too many of?  Monitors!  Loads of 'em](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYHxc57IGmM)

### Co-Op Achievements

#### Completion Achievements

You will get these achievements simply by completing all of the co-op courses

- **Team Building** - Complete all test chambers in the Team Building co-op course
- **Confidence Building** - Complete all test chambers in the Mass and Velocity co-op course
- **Bridge Building** - Complete all test chambers in the Hard-Light Surfaces co-op course
- **Obstacle Building** - Complete all test chambers in the Excursion Funnels co-op course
- **You Saved Science** - Complete all test chambers in all courses of co-op
- **High Five** - Celebrate your cooperative calibration success - *Simply do the high-five gesture after completing the co-op calibration course* (comes automatically after finishing calibration course)

#### Optional Achievements

You actually have to earn these by doing specific tasks in co-op

- **Iron Grip** - Never lose a cube in Chamber 6 of the Mass and Velocity co-op course
- **Gesticul-8** - Perform all 8 gestures of your own volition in co-op - *No explanation needed*
- **Can't Touch This** - Dance in front of a turret blocked by a hard light bridge in co-op - *No explanation needed*
- **Empty Gesture** - Drop your co-op partner in goo while they are gesturing by removing the bridge under them - *You monster*
- **Party of Three** - Find the hidden companion cube in co-op test chamber - [See it here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yz8Z0PWxSUQ)
- **Narbacular Drop** - Place a portal under your co-op partner while they are gesturing - *No explanation needed*
- **Professor Portal** - After completing co-op, complete Calibration Course online with a friend who hasn’t played before
- **Air Show** - Perform 2 aerial gestures before touching the ground in co-op
- **Portal Conservation Society** - Complete Chamber 3 in the Hard-Light Surfaces co-op course using only 5 total portal placements - [Here's how it's done](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXUgbInwimA)
- **Four Ring Circus** - Enter 4 different portals without touching the ground in co-op
- **Triple Crown** - Solve 3 co-op chambers in the Mass and Velocity course in under 60 seconds each - [See how it's done](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WcfOgXUsJ8)
- **Still Alive** - Complete Course 4 with neither you nor your co-op partner dying - *No explanation needed*
- **Asking for Trouble** - Taunt GLaDOS in front of a camera in each of the five co-op courses - *No explanation needed*
- **Rock Portal Scissors** - Win 3 co-op games of rock-paper-scissors in a row - *Good luck!*
- **Friends List With Benefits** - While playing co-op, hug 3 different people on your friends list - *Awwww*